# creating DynamicDataContextDriver for linqpad with c#

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am trying to create driver for `linqpad` and have question:

When I am creating `DynamicDataContextDriver`, I must create class `TypedDataContext`.

1. What I should put in it?
2. How will it be populated?
3. Can I control how will it be populated?
4. If I use object database here, is there something that I must bear in mind?

I found some answer [here](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/comment/47/#Comment_45), but I can not find there all the above answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typed data context is simply a class with properties/fields suitable for querying. Those properties/fields will typically return IEnumerables or IQueryables. For example:

```
public class TypedDataContext
{
   public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get { ... } }
   public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get { ... } }
   ...
}
```

When you use Visual Studio to create a new item of kind "LINQ to SQL classes" or "ADO.NET Entity Data Model", Visual Studio creates a typed data context for you which is an excellent example of what LINQPad expects. A typed data context can also expose methods (e.g., to map stored procedures or functions) - in fact it can expose anything that makes sense to the end user.

When you execute a query in LINQPad that has a connection, LINQPad subclasses the typed data context associated with the connection so that the query has access to all of its fields/properties. This is why `Customers.Dump()` is a valid query - we can just access `Customers` without having to instantiate the typed data context first.

A LINQPad driver can work in one of two ways. Either it can act like Visual Studio and build the typed data context automatically and on the fly (*dynamic* data context driver), or it can extract a typed data context from an existing assembly provided by the user (*static* data context driver). When you add a connection in LINQPad, you'll notice that the drivers are listed in two list boxes (**Build data context automatically** = *dynamic driver*, and **Use a typed data context from your own assembly** = *static driver*).

The typed data context is instantiated whenever a query executes. Because its properties typically return lazily evaluated IEnumerables/IQueryables, it's not helpful to think of "populating" it. However, it will need to know how to access an underlying data source, and this is done by [passing arguments into the constructor](http://www.linqpad.net/extensibility.aspx).

LINQPad normally keeps the query's application domain alive between query runs, and this might be useful with caching and optimization should you be writing a driver for an object database. Other than that, there shouldn't be any special considerations for object databases.